# I am trying to make an existing sparql code to do some added function

Tags: sparql

I have this sparql query which gets me a list of winners of a tournament. for example the us open, below is the original code

```
SELECT ?year ?winnerLabel 
      WHERE {   ?event wdt:P361/wdt:P31 wd:Q220347;       
              wdt:P585 ?year ; wdt:P1346 ?winner   
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } } 
ORDER BY DESC(?year)
```

this is the modified code where I wanted to add nationality and sex but it dosen't work , please help me fix

```
SELECT ?year ?winnerLabel ?sex ?nationality
      WHERE {   ?event wdt:P361/wdt:P31 wd:Q41520;       
              wdt:P585 ?year ; wdt:P1346 ?winner ; wdt:P27 ?nationality; wdt:P21 ?sex
                       
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } } 
ORDER BY DESC(?year)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the `?winner` for the nationality/sex, not the `?event`.

```
?event wdt:P361/wdt:P31 wd:Q41520 ;       
       wdt:P585 ?year ; 
       wdt:P1346 ?winner .

?winner wdt:P27 ?nationality ; 
        wdt:P21 ?sex .
```